# Compare Button Label value to string variable

Tags: string-comparison, swiftui

I'm trying to write a simple quiz app. Upon a user tapping a button, I want the action to compare the Button's label to see if it matches the variable of "correctChoice"

I tried the following if/then statement but it doesn't seem to work, as I'm getting the following error "Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'self' is immutable"

//Variables Used

```
var model = Question.all()
var questionNumber: Int = 1
var totalQuestions: Int = 100
var timeLeft: Int = 60
var currentScore: Int = 0
```

//Button Code

```
Button(action: {
                 if Question.all()[0].choice1 == Question.all()[0].correctChoice {
                            currentScore += 10
                        } else {
                            currentScore += 0
                        }  
                    }) {
                        Text(Question.all()[0].choice1)
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                    }
```

Comment: As mentioned in the **correct** answer, you probably should put all of this in a model. (That's why I'm adding a comment along with the upvote.)  Consider this: (1) Your model is simply two (or more) `ObservableObject` classes of type `Question` and `Player`. (2) You can expose this as either an `EnvironmentObject` or `ObservedObject`. (3) Properly done it maintains state. Conclusion? To "interact" between SwiftUI and your "variable" - which is *not* a UI element but instead something stored - you need to make it "mutable" to SwiftUI by making it `@State`.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I'm new to coding, I'm a UX designer. I definitely will read up on Objects. Currently, I only have the questions and answers in my model.

Answer (score 2):

`currentScore` should be a `@State` variable to be mutable inside a struct. Or it can be inside a model.